# Prove: if $A$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix such that $A^3 = A$, then $\det(A) = 0, -1,$ or $1$.

Tags: matrices

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix such that $A^3 = A$, then $\det(A) = 0, -1,$ or $1$.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that $\det (AB) = \det A \cdot \det B$?

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\det(A B) = \det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure how to use that fact

Answer (score 5):

Using the fact that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, we see that

$$\det(A)^3 = \det(A)$$

What are the solutions to $x^3 = x$?

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple and is as follows. We know that $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$. Making use of this property we have $$det(A^3) = det(A)^3 = det(A).$$ If we set $det(A) = x$ then we merely have to solve $x^3 = x$. Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome!